# Restore multiple .BAK files from device at once in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I am able restore one .BAK file to SQL server with below query but now I want to restore multiple .BAK files at once, is it possible to restore?

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'alliance_application' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'alliance_application_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks_log.ldf'
```

Comment: If you want to restore multiple files at the same time, you'll need to open multiple connections and run them at the same time. You can't define simultaneous restores in a single T-SQL statement; they will be completed one after the other.

Comment: When you say this `but now I want to restore multiple .BAK files at once, is it possible to restore?` I assume they are different database bak files..If this is the case, you can do it in multiple ways,one  way is to write a cursor

Comment: Depends on what's *in* those .BAK files. `RESTORE` can restore from multiple files at once, but only if the backup was split across those files in the first place. That's probably not what you're asking about.

Comment: @JeroenMostert raises a good point, which might make mine and his comments confusing. When I say files, I mean files for different databases entirely; not a database made up of multiple files.

Comment: I've copied the above script and pasted multiple times for different .BAK files to retrieve them at a time and it's working fine but execution taking one minute 20 seconds to retrieve eight backup files. **Now I need to improve execution performance to few seconds** can any one please help in this???